# How to deselect duplicate entries in a query?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I've got a query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM RecipeTable, RecipeIngredientTable, SyncRecipeIngredientTable
 WHERE RecipeTable.recipe_id = SyncRecipeIngredientTable.recipe_id
   AND RecipeIngredientTable.recipe_ingredient_id =
       SyncRecipeIngredientTable.recipe_ingredient_id
   AND RecipeIngredientTable.recipe_item_name in ("ayva", "pirinç", "su")
 GROUP by RecipeTable.recipe_id
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;
```

and this query returns the result like this:

[image: query result]

As you can see in the image there is 3 duplicate, unnecessary entries (no, i can't delete them because of the multiple foreign keys). How can I deselect these duplicate entries from the result query? In the end I want to return 6 entries not 9.

Comment: They are not duplicates. They have different recipe_ids and this is the column you group by.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*What you want to eliminate in the result set is not duplication of `recipe_id` values but `recipe_name` values.*

You just need to **group**(**partition**) by **recipe_name** through use of `ROW_NUMBER()` analytic function :

```
SELECT recipe_id, author_name ...
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY recipe_name) AS rn,
          sr.recipe_id, author_name ...
     FROM SyncRecipeIngredientTable sr
     JOIN RecipeIngredientTable ri 
       ON ri.recipe_ingredient_id = sr.recipe_ingredient_id
     JOIN RecipeTable rt
       ON rt.recipe_id = sr.recipe_id
    WHERE ri.recipe_item_name in ("ayva", "pirinç", "su")
  )
  WHERE rn = 1
```

This way, you can pick only one of the records with `rn=1` (*`ORDER BY` Clause might be added to that analytic function after `PARTITION BY` clause if spesific record is needed to be picked*)